# Pure Gui testing using VNC

Tags: user-interface, automated-tests, ui-testing, vnc

I need to test complex gui interface, with many widgets written in I think Qt.
Now I use opencv, vnc, vncdotool, pytesseract and some other tools.
It works but it's not easy to write the test and I cannot include anyone who is not very good in the tools above. It is also not easy to update the code if something changes in gui.
I searched for some convenient tool, but it's all same heavily web browser based tools that are searching for objects.
Is there a user friendly automation tool, where I could grab an image via VNC, verify that is expected, read some ocr, send key strokes, move/drag the mouse etc.. ?

Answer (score 1):

I've just read a book that mentions a VNC-based testing project (Experiences of Test Automation). The book is a few years old but mentions Eggplant and VNCRobot - might be worth checking, if you are still needing something.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, vncdotool, pytesseract, opencv is the way to go for kind of pure gui test.
Everything I found around is based on these programs/tools.
I created kind of capture tool, to select an image and create line of codes. I might post on github one day.
So you need:

- vncdotool
  vncdotool to grab a screenshot, or even region withing the screen
  vncdotool to send keyboard actions, and mouse clicks or mouse drags
- opencv
  opencv to find image object within a screenshot, and get coordinates of the object
  (than using vnctodotool send mouse click to the coordinates)
- pytesseract
  tesseract, it could be used with/without python wrapper. Text recognition. Pretty good idea to minimize use of teceract ocr reader for anything compicated.

That's all. Tool I use works equaly good on windows and linux. I do development in windows. Tipically capture object and send mouse clicks or keyboard actions.
There's simple routine finding the object using opencv, with the threshold that varies but not too much.
It's simple you end up building enough methods that later speeds up the development.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write tests with CuteDriver for the Qt application.

https://github.com/cutedriver

One example test is here:
https://github.com/cutedriver/cutedriver-examples/blob/master/examples/quickapp/tests/fute/cases/test_button.rb